# View git source control in Visual studio

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfvc

Im using Visual Studio 2015 and want to view the server tree\ source control in my studio as I view it with TFVC.

When I create a TFVC project I can see it in source control but not when creating a git project.

Is it possible to have git source control in visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the **source control** button the same as TFVC in team explorer with GIT. There's no this feature, it's by designed. And there actually **isn't a way** to navigate your Git repo inside VS yet.

However, you can view it through **web portal** such as   `http://yourserver:8080/tfs/YourGitProject`

Moreover, using GIT with Visual Studio, you  can also use some extensions such as this one **[Git Source Control Provider 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/51e11ccc-6334-4873-912d-bf5025eb115d)**.

Comment: I wanted to eliminate the use of the web portal and navigate the repo with VS. I think it's more comfprtable but I guess there isn't a way to do it.

Comment: Is there any other studio except VS that support team and solution explorer and also can navigate in server repository as well?

Comment: @chen  Afraid not, at least there is no such things in the Microsoft products.   With other company 's product, should also not use team and solution explorer, I guess.